# Set Div width auto to span Text?

Tags: html, css

Basically I've:

```
<div>
   <span>Keep parent div width auto to this text</span>
</div>
```

Simply I need to set the `div` width extend to `span` Text.

Tried this but didn't worked :

```
div{
    position:absolute;
    height:50px;
    width:auto;
    background:#1a5f8c;
    border:1px solid #14496d;
    display:inline-block;
}
span{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    text-align: left;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:500;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    color:#ddd;
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x0r4oz86/

All replies are much appreciated :)

Comment: Does it have to be positioned absolutely? Is it ok for you to use javascript/jquery to make this work?

Comment: like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BpvZKE

Comment: @LL is right. If you take off the absolute positioning on the div it will work as expected.

Comment: @LL I don't think jquery or javascript would be required though

Comment: just change `position:absolute;` to `position:relative;` to your `span`

Comment: @Jaywardan I couldn't think of a pure css solution on top of my head if the element has to be positioned absolutely... Might be wrong though :)

Comment: This is quit embarrassing when you just need to remove `position` and you can't figure it out. anyway it worked thank all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove `position:absolute` from your `span` element

Here is the working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/x0r4oz86/1/

Comment: @Jay wardan, is this solution OK for your case?